# Super Replace Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have 12,000 cells in an excel sheet, each cell has one out of 2,000 categories (so, there are several cells with the same category), something like;

```
1- A
2- B
3- C
4- A
5- A
6- B
7- AA
8- AB
...
12000- AAZ
```

And I have another sheet containing two columns with a number for each category (column A= the category name & column B= the corresponding value), like;

```
column A   column B
A           1.5
B           2.3
```

......

Now, I want any possible function to help me replace the values in these 12000 cells with the corresponding number. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=INDEX()` and `MATCH()` will help you out!

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, can you clarify more?
What to write inside the ()?
Sorry for my question

Comment: @MohamedGomaaKamel `VLOOKUP()` will also do and may be easier to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: Sheet1 has your 12,000 cells in column A

Assumption: Sheet2 is your reference sheet

Then in cell `Sheet1!B1`:

**INDEX/MATCH**

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),2)`

**VLOOKUP**

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

On a large dataset use the first option as it is faster!

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX(D:E,MATCH(A1,$CD$1:$D$4,0),2)

Considering your Column D:E has your ref data and Column A and B having large data set. Type above formula in column C